# How to make auto-completion case sensitive?

Tags: spacemacs, auto-complete-mode

`spacemacs` default configuration enables auto-completion, however by default its case insensitive.

How to make `auto-complete` case sensitive (specifically using a `spacemacs` configuration)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your `~/.emacs`, `(setq ac-ignore-case nil)`.

For spacemacs this can be done by editing `~/.spacemacs` file:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  ;; add the line below to the user-config section
  (setq ac-ignore-case nil)
  )
```